# Why does id() of an unbound method in Python 2 change for every access

Tags: python, python-2.x

Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Oct  1 2012, 22:07:21) 
[GCC 4.4.3]

```
>>> class myclass:
...     def func(self):
...             pass

>>> dd = myclass.func
>>> ee = myclass.func
>>> cc = myclass.func
>>> ff = myclass.func
>>> ss = myclass.func
>>> uu = myclass.func
>>> pp = myclass.func
>>> 
>>> 
>>> id(dd) ; id(cc) ; id(ee) ; id(ff) ; id(ss) ; id(uu) ; id(pp)
3074535252L
3074534772L
3074522444L
3074531732L
3074497588L
3073003604L
3073003724L
```

Why is the ID of the unbound method different each time?

Shouldn't it be same ?

Comment: Does the same happen with new style classes?

Comment: @Tadeck Let me try now. EDIT: Yes it does.

Comment: That the id() is the address is an irrelevant implementation detail. I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't methods have reference equality?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977808/why-dont-methods-have-reference-equality)

Answer (score 6):

This is because the methods on a class (old or new) work really like attributes with the descriptor `__get__` method; On python 2 the code

```
foo = FooClass.bar_method
```

is analogous to

```
import types
foo = types.MethodType(FooClass.__dict__['bar_method'], None, FooClass)
```

It will create a new instance of `instancemethod(bar_method, None, FooClass)` on each access. The original function is available as `FooClass.bar_method.im_func` and the class instance in `foo.im_class`. The type for both bound and unbound methods is the same `instancemethod`; if the `im_self` member is `None`, the `instancemethod` instance has the repr `<unbound method ...>`, whereas if im_self member is not None, the repr is `<bound method...>`

Python 3 is different. Unbound methods have a repr `<function x.f at 0x7fd419cf69e0>` and the id is always the same, that is they are just general functions. In Python 3 you can pass anything for `self` of an unbound undecorated method, even `None`, it is just a function with a dot in its name.

Comment: This does not happen for bound methods. Different instances of bound methods all have same function object.

Comment: Could you prove it with the code? Without proof (eg. documentation or working code) it is just a guess.

Comment: @Tadeck, I tried it. Please go ahead and give it a shot. I used im_func attribute to get the func object associated with the different bound method instances.

Comment: @Tadeck You are right the behavior in the question does not happen on Python3.

Comment: The unbound method is not a function object in python 2.