# Why does comparing methods with `is` always return False?

Tags: python

Why does this return `False`

```
>>> class A:
...     def a_method(self):
...         pass
...     def b(self):
...         print(self.a_method is self.a_method)
... 
>>> c = A()
>>> c.b()
False
>>> c.a_method is c.a_method
False
```

when you can use `is` for functions

```
>>> def a(): pass
... 
>>> a is a
True
```

Comment: :D most obscure indeed: `id(c.a) == id(c.a)` but not `c.a is c.a`

Comment: seems that `id(self.a_method)` returns a different value everytime... `==` works

Comment: `id(c.a) == id(c.a)` is not an indication that it's the same. id can be reused

Comment: Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264578

Comment: and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977808/why-dont-methods-have-reference-equality