# What is the right way to test for equality between a Python variable and a callable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the right way to compare if a variable contains a callable I want? Should I use the `is` operator or the `==` operator?

In the following interactive session, I define two callables, `f` and `g`. I assign one to variable `a` and another to variable `b`.

Now, when I want to check if `a` is same as `f` or not, both `a == f` and `a is f` work.

```
>>> def f():
...     pass
...
>>> def g():
...     pass
...
>>> a = f
>>> b = g
>>> a == f
True
>>> a is f
True
>>> a == g
False
>>> a is g
False
>>> b == f
False
>>> b is f
False
>>> b == g
True
>>> b is g
True
```

My questions.

1. Is using one operator better than the other?
2. Is there a situation where one operator would produce a different result than the other?

Comment: I don't see anything in the question linked as duplicate that answers my question.

Comment: @LoneLearner: it tells you that function objects are only equal if they are the same object. It tells you why `f == g` is true only if `f is g` is true.

Comment: @LoneLearner: What part of *is true only if* is unclear here?

Comment: @LoneLearner: if you wanted to know about that in a context **other than functions** you did not make that clear.

Comment: @LoneLearner: you just expanded your question to methods, which is a *different issue altogether*.

Comment: I voted to close, yet I upvoted you ;). If what you ask is not the same with that post, make it clear plz. You could edit you yourselves' answer to a question, and then will get votes to reopen ;)

Comment: Given the number of border cases already underlined by others below and above, I would only write code that depend on function equality if I can control that equality, i.e. I would define a class instead of a function, put the executable code in `__call__` and my concept of equality in `__eq__`. In that situation `==`returns another result than `is`. 
Hmmm, that sounds like a lot of boiler plate, so I guess I'd rather try not to need function equality in the first place actually. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two functions are only equal if they are the same object.

In other words, `f == g` is *only* true if `f is g` is also true. The latter is faster, so just use `is`.

Don't confuse this with methods; Python produces new method objects each time you access the object through attribute access (through the use of [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html)).

So:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self): pass

f = Foo()
f.bar is f.bar
```

is always `False` because methods are created a-new on each attribute access. If you wanted to compare if they convey the same *function* you need to access the actual function object:

```
f.bar.__func__ is f.bar.__func__
```

*is* true.

Unlike functions, methods do implement an `__eq__` equality method; see [Why don't methods have reference equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977808/why-dont-methods-have-reference-equality)

Comment: `is` should also be preferred because it's more idiomatic here. Functions don't conceptually have a value, only an identity.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: they do have a value; byte code, argument defaults, a name, and more. Python functions are first class objects, you can still try and test if functions will execute the same code, for example.

Comment: @LoneLearner: Yet I *tell you at the end* what to use, and why.

Comment: @LoneLearner: I tell you to use `is`, and that there is no situation where `==` will return a different value. What else did you ask?

Comment: +1 for the edited part ;)