# How to update the the class type and methods in an existing object

Tags: python

If I have an object of a certain type, and I would like to get the unbound method, should I use `type(obj).method_name` or `obj.__class__.method_name`? I got confused upon seeing the following result:

```
class ClassA(object):
  def Test(self):
    pass

obj_a = ClassA()

print obj_a.__class__ is type(obj_a)
print obj_a.__class__.Test is type(obj_a).Test
```

The first returns True and the second False. So what is the difference of the two in the last statement?

UPDATE:

My use case is that I have some class in a playground notebook. The class objects may be heavy, for example, they contain stuff after long time of training. During the time I would like to make updates to the functions and keep use the existing objects. So I would like something like this to be working:

```
# In cell 1 I define the following class.
class ClassA(object):
  def Test(self):
    print 'haha'

# In cell 2 I create an object and use it for a while.
obj_a = ClassA()
obj_a.Test()

# After some time I modified the ClassA in cell 1 and re-executed the cell:
class ClassA(object):
  def Test(self):
    print 'hoho'

# Then I want to replace a method and call Test again:
obj_a.__class__.Test = ClassA.Test
obj_a.Test()  # Should print 'hoho'
```

Unfortunately the above code does not work. The last call `obj_a.Test()` uses the unbound method `Test`.

Comment: @user3100115: I thought they should both return the type object of `obj_a`?

Comment: why would you want to get the method of the class? That's practically useless. Take the method from an instance ``obj_a.Test``.

Comment: That would give me a bounded method..

Comment: If you compare the two by `==` instead of `is`, you will find them to be two equal (yet not identical) unbound method objects. `__class__`  and `type()`, on the other hand, both return the identical (since only) type `ClassA`.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but if you take an unbound method from a class you need to pass the first argument (``self``) explicitly. So you unbound it to bind it at call-time? Your question is interesting but I cannot see any real use-case here. Also with python 3.5 both statements return True on my computer.

Comment: In Py3, these both return True. Not sure why the second doesn't return True for py2, checking the `id`s they are identical.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: I see. The `.Test` may be returning a dynamically constructed unbound method, such that the two are equal but not identical. Not sure though.

Comment: @AChampion: Interesting. There must be something I didn't understand about `is`.

Comment: @MSeifert: Do you mean the "unbound" is some procedure that is performed under the hood? Do you know what is the procedure?

Comment: This is the expected behaviour is. change the second example to:

`a = obj_a.__class__.Test`

`b = type(obj_a).Test`

`a is b` will return `True`

Comment: @shaoyl85 - Just try ``obj_a.__class__.Test()`` (unbound method) and then try ``obj_a.__class__.Test(obj_a)`` (unbound method with binding at call time). If you want a "unbound" method use ``@staticmethod`` or ``@classmethod``

Comment: @user3100115 Hmm.. it is still False for me (Python 2.7.10).

Comment: @shaoyl85 this can be boiled down to `ClassA.Test is ClassA.Test` returns `False` in Py2, this seems very strange.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions. I updated the question with some motivation. Would you have a look again?

Comment: @schwobaseggl yes False in Python2.x and True in Python3.x

Comment: @shaoyl85 - If you can use Python3, your example is working there because from python3 on methods are just functions (there is no real bound function anymore). Not really sure if that's exactly true but it's true enough for your example. You should probably add a ``Python 2`` tag to the question because the question is irrelevant for python 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python bound and unbound method object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348031/python-bound-and-unbound-method-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question, you need to assign to the bound method, e.g.:

```
import types
obj_a.Test = types.MethodType(ClassA.Test, obj_a)
obj_a.Test()
```

Would give the result you expect, i.e. `'hoho'`

*Updated*: Here's an example:

```
import types

class ClassA(object):
    def Test(self):
        print 'haha'

obj = ClassA()
obj.Test()
# haha
```

Update ClassA to `hoho`:

```
obj.__class__ = ClassA
obj.Test()
# hoho
```

Comment: Thank you! Are you trying it in Python 3? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I see. My use case is little different. In the ipython notebook, I modify on the `Test` method directly and then execute that cell. In this case a new class will be created with the same name "ClassA". I would like to replace the `Test` method in `obj` with the method `Test` in the new class `ClassA`. Is there a way of doing so?

Comment: You will also need to assign `obj.__class__ == ClassA` as it is a new `ClassA` for it to work correctly, fixed above.

Comment: Actually, just `obj.__class__ = ClassA` is enough. There is no need for the `MethodType`. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, updated - I initially tried that and got an error but tested again and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can try also :

```
obj_a.__class__.Test is obj_a.__class__.Test
type(obj_a).Test is type(obj_a).Test
```

which both are equivalent to `ClassA.Test is ClassA.Test`, but all of them returns `False`.

Explanation for this is the particular behavior unbounded methods, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977808/why-dont-methods-have-reference-equality).

Comment: Interesting. The `.Test` may not be returning an existing object, but are dynamically constructing one.

Comment: Btw, this is explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348031/python-bound-and-unbound-method-object