# Is it a good idea to use "is" to check which function is contained in a variable?

Tags: python, equality

I have a variable that contains a function.

```
def foo(x):
    return x + 42

def bar(x):
    return x - 42

my_var = foo
```

I want to check if that function is a certain function. Should I use `is` or `==`?

```
my_var == foo
my_var == bar
```

and

```
my_var is foo
my_var is bar
```

both return what I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should use `==`.

A good rule of thumb is only use `is` when doing `is None` or `is not None` and nowhere else. In this case, comparing *functions* with `is` works, but if you try to compare a *method* of an instance of a class with itself you'll get `False` (even on the same instance), whereas comparing with `==` returns what you expect:

```
>>> class A:
...     def my_method(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.my_method is a.my_method
False
>>> a.my_method == a.my_method
True
```

Better to avoid having to remember this and always compare functions with `==`.

See this question: [Why don't methods have reference equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977808/why-dont-methods-have-reference-equality)

Answer (score 4):

They are the same thing for a function object. The `==` operator calls the `__eq__` function to perform the comparison. The `function` object does not define an `__eq__` method:

```
>>> def foo():
...   pass
... 
>>> foo.__eq__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__eq__'
```

Therefore the interpreter uses the default implementation in [PyObject](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/object.c#L807):

```
res = (v == w) ? Py_True : Py_False;
```

which is basically a pointer comparison, essentially the same as `is`.

Comment: Turns out this isn't true for object methods.

Answer (score 0):

Is checks for the identity of an object.  If you assign `foo` to `myvar`, then an alias is created and they both have the same id (in the case of functions at least).

Checking 2 functions for equivalence from a mathematical standpoint entails checking the equivalence of the domains and codomains of both functions.

So `is` is better.