# classmethod returns a new object on each access

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle, python-3.7, class-method

Accessing `classmethod` of a class always return a different object. This is unlike instance or static methods.

```
class Foo(object):
    @classmethod
    def foo_classmethod(cls):
        pass

    def foo_instancemethod(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def foo_staticmethod():
        pass
```

and when tried to compare

```
In [37]: print(Foo.foo_instancemethod is Foo.foo_instancemethod)
True

In [38]: print(Foo.foo_staticmethod is Foo.foo_staticmethod)
True

In [39]: print(Foo.foo_classmethod is Foo.foo_classmethod)
False
```

This behavior is same in Python 2 and 3. **Does this look like a bug?** I came across this while pickling a classmethod in Python3 and doing the `is` check on the unpickled object.

Comment: This is normal and expected. Note, instance methods do this too, when accessed via an instance.

Comment: So, this explains what's going on, although it doesn't address `classmethod` specifically, and there are no unbound methods in Python 3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977808/why-dont-methods-have-reference-equality