# __getattr__ returns different ids on other object's getattr()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've stumbled upon a curious behavior in python while trying to implement an object wrapper. Consider the following code (I've simplified it from the case I've encountered to show its very basics):

```
class A(object):
    def hello(self):
        print "hello ",

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.obj, attr)
    def regular_func(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.obj, attr)
a=A()
b=B(a)

for x in xrange(10):
    print id(b.hello), ",",
print
for x in xrange(10):
    print id(a.hello), ",",
print
for x in xrange(10):
    print id(A.hello), ",",
print
for x in xrange(10):
    print id(b.regular_func("hello")), ",",
print
for x in xrange(10):
    b.hello()
```

The output of the above script will be:

```
4375335072 , 4375100144 , 4375335072 , 4375100144 , 4375335072 , 4375100144 , 4375335072 , 4375100144 , 4375335072 , 4375100144 ,
4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 ,
4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 ,
4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 , 4375100144 ,
hello  hello  hello  hello  hello  hello  hello  hello  hello  hello
```

Notice how the ids toggle between two values whenever the `__getattr__` is invoked (the first row printed)? I've messed around with it a bit, this happens for `__getattribute__` as well, but notice it never happens when calling `regular_func`. It always toggles between two values, and always toggles (not randomly).

This still happens even when I change the `__getattr__` to such:

```
a=A()
class B(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(a, attr)
```

Or as such:

```
a=A()
class B(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return a.__getattribute__(attr)
```

And in the above example, repeatedly printing `id(a.__getattribute__("hello"))` always gives the same number.

Can anyone explain this peculiar behavior, or suggest any further ideas to investigate?

Comment: wow, that looks like some CPython PyObject caching madness.. interesting. Have you asked in `#python` on `irc.freenode.net` ?

Comment: Isn't `b.hello` just a bound method? what do you expect its id() to be? The boundmethod object gets created each time you access `b.hello`, then freed. Even if you replace it with `id(b.hello())`, you just get the id() of None (because b.hello() returns None).

Comment: @shx2 `b.hello` isn't bound to `b`, and notice that it toggles the id between the id of `a.hello` and something else..

Comment: It's bound to `a`. What's the difference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639908/why-is-a-method-not-identical-to-itself

Comment: @shx2 the difference is that `id(a.hello)` always yields the same value, whereas sometimes `id(a.hello) == id(b.hello)`, and sometimes it isn't.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks, that's a good explanation, but then I would expect all the ids I get to be random, but they aren't. The behavior is quite consistent, so I'm still confused. I know now not to rely on ids for comparison of methods, but I would much rather understand what happens underneath the hood.

Comment: They won't be random under CPython since the result of `id()` is the memory address of the object. They will be arbitrary but deterministic.

Comment: How are you planning to use those id()'s? If you're not, why are you trying to make sense of them?

Comment: @shx2 I don't plan to use the ids, I was trying to figure out why `a.hello is not b.hello`, which got me to investigate the ids. And I'm always trying to make sense of things, as the deeper you dive the more you know. Knowledge is power. Information is liberating. Education is the premise of progress. The pen is mightier than the sword. And some other cliches ;)

Comment: I tried this example out myself and I can confirm that the id of b.hello does alternate. But comparisons seem to *never* alternate. What's even more mind boggling is the following: `>>> c = id(b.hello); c == id(a.hello)
True
>>> id(a.hello) == id(b.hello)
False
` Both statements are consistent no matter how many times you run them.

Comment: @micromoses information about bound methods is liberating indeed! :)